# Identify current ui view from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a guy to know in which ui view a controller is in?

The problem that I have is that a two element(object) array is being sent to a state. Each element of said array is supposed to render in each of my `ui-view`s. The order in which the elements is rendered depends on one of the keys provided in the object. Once I have the value of the key, I can render the views where they correspond, but without knowing the name of the view in which the controller is acting, I can't determine the order.

This is a sample response that I would be getting.

```
    "resources": [
      {
        "video":"http://url.to/some/video+on+the+server",
        "position": 1
      }, {
        "image":"http://placehold.it/600x450&text=img2",
        "position": 0 
      }
    ]
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
<div class="parent"><div class="col-md-6" ui-view="left"></div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="col-md-6" ui-view="righ"></div></div>
```

The content of each view is dependent on the position key that each object has. This is the state responsible for this:

```
.state('media', {
  url: '/media',
  views: {
    'left': {
      templateUrl: '../js/media/media.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'MediaController as mediaCtrl'
    },
    'right': {
      templateUrl: '../js/media/media.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'MediaController as mediaCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I read you question so many times but didn't get any clue, actually what you wanted..but by looking at code found issue with state..so I added the answer..can you eloborate more in question what exactly you want..

Comment: can you elaborate more on what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Your state should configuration should be,

**Code**

```
.state('media', {
  url: '/media',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: '../js/media/baseTemplate.html',
      controller: 'ParentController as parentCtrl'
    },
    'left@media': {
      templateUrl: '../js/media/media.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'MediaController as mediaCtrl'
    },
    'right@media': {
      templateUrl: '../js/media/media.tmpl.html',
      controller: 'MediaController as mediaCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: please do upvote if it does help you.with route states.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up identifying the instance of each controller by creating a service that essentially acts as a global counter. Upon controller instantiation, it makes a call to the service and returns its current index. The service increments a private variable upon each call. This is what the service ended up looking like:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('screenIdentifier', [])
    .factory('screenIdentifier', screenIdentifier);

      screenIdentifier.$inject = [];

      function screenIdentifier() {
      var _currentIndex = 0;

      return {
        getCurrentIndex: getCurrentIndex,
        resetIndex: resetIndex,
        assignPosition: assignPosition
      };

      function assignPosition() {
        return _currentIndex += 1;
      }
   }
})();
```

By knowing the index of each controller, I can properly identify the index of the view.